# Which is better approach between holding object in memory or storing data in some file/database

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, memory-management, data-structures, architecture

I am working on a dashboard project which connects with two or three bug tracking system like jira, mantis etc.. and display graphical representation of data in web app.

What I am doing:

When any new project gets added, I connect and fetch data from these system and stores data in one table in database. After that there is web app which then process this data in table and displays charts and tables.

For updating, I have created a windows service which then continuously connect with bug tracking system and update table in database (Project configuration data is also stored in one another table)

Question:

1. What if I don't store bug tracking system data into database and store that data into object. Will create a web service which will fire update events upon update and will then refresh view?
2. What is right approach? Is it right to store whole project data into memory rather than database. What if there will be large number of project say 300 or 600?
3. How should I decide when to store data in memory and when in database?
4. Pros and cons of both ways?

Comment: How big is a project data ? We can't guess that.

Comment: It's quite large. For 20 project right now have around 10000 rows with 12 columns then other meta and config data in different tables.

Comment: How much in KB (or MB or GB) ?

Comment: Size of database is 32 MB right now

Comment: Then RAM should be quite sufficient (1 GB for 600 projects). But keeping all that data volatile is pretty risky.

Comment: It's unclear to me what data you're contemplating storing. Is your app updating data in the bug tracking systems? Or is it just getting info from those systems and storing it locally? In general, though, whether you want to use a database or keep everything in memory is usually based on what you want to happen if the system goes down.

Comment: My app is not updating data in bug tracking system. It is only getting info from these systems and storing it locally. I wanted to make my system just like share market where the tools is live and whenever there is any change happen in bug tracking system, It will get reflect to our tool instantly. In this case if I choose database for storage there will be some lag but if I choose memory it will be very fast but if the number of project goes up the memory option doesn't seem so good.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I don't store bug tracking system data into database and store
>   that data into object. Will create a web service which will fire
>   update events upon update and will then refresh view?

You lose two benefits of "data base": consistency (data persists after a crash), and you need more RAM, which is more expensive and scarce than disk/flash.

Data base also gives easier versioning control using standard libraries (so you can rollback to previous version if need arises).

Either way, you should use libraries that support your desired operations and don't try to reinvent the wheel.

> What is right approach? Is it right to store whole project data into
>   memory rather than database. What if there will be large number of
>   project say 300 or 600?

If you don't care about losing data if your server crashes/reloaded for update, and you can afford the RAM - you can make it work. Otherwise, it is probably a better idea to use database.

> How should I decide when to store data in memory and when in database?

How tolerant do you want to be to failures, and how much RAM you can afford.

> Pros and cons of both ways?

Pros of database: Better consistency, cheaper

Pros of objects: faster (disk read is slower than RAM), lesser dependencies of the system's state.